# 2008 impala noisy power steering pump

Tags: chevrolet, power-steering, impala

I have had a noisy power steering pump each of the last three years in cold weather on my 2008 Impala. It has been replaced twice, and is now noisy again. My mechanic is stumped. What else can be causing this? I can't believe that I could need a third pump in three years.

Comment: Welcome, and thank you for contributing a question! It would be nice to know a bit more about this. For example, when the pump is replaced, does the noise go away? Does it also go away now when the weather gets warmer? What does the noise sound like? Do you ever have to top up the power steering fluid?

Comment: Did they replace the steering rack with the pump? It is possible that whatever failed in the first pump deposited metal bits in the steering rack. They (the dealer) replaced my 08 Impala steering rack under warranty when the pump failed in 2010.

Comment: It is better when it is warmer outside. t

Comment: It  is quiet when it is warm outside. It makes a loud whining noise only in cold weather. The steering rack has not been replaced. The noise went away last winter when the pump was replaced, but returned this year when it turned colder. the fluid level never goes down